# Issue in AngularJS show/order data on specific criteria

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have an issue regarding filter data on some criteria in AngularJS. I want to show/order all filled fields first then in the end all fields having data ("-"). As filter is inside ng-repeat so, I want to run the filter only once which is I know not possible as AngularJS using 'dirty checking'.

```
'appStatusData'= 
             Data-A: "0.000"
             Data-Date: "2014-09-07 00:00:00.0"
             Data-B: "111"
             Data-C: "-"
             Data-D: "0517"
             Data-E: "462.000"
             Data-F: "-"
             Data-G: "No"
             Data-H: "-"
```

Expected Output:

```
            Data-A: "0.000"
            Data-Date: "2014-09-07 00:00:00.0"
            Data-B: "111"
            Data-D: "0517"
            Data-E: "462.000"
            Data-G: "No"
            Data-C: "-"
            Data-F: "-"
            Data-H: "-"

<ion-view view-title="Application Status" name="permit-view">
<ion-header-bar class="bar-stable bar-subheader">
    <div class="title" style="color: #2A4660"><u>Header</u></div>
</ion-header-bar>
<ion-content class="padding" has-subheader=true>
    <ion-list>
        <ion-item class="item" ng-repeat="(key, val) in (appStatusData | showDecimalData | showDataByNotNullFirst ) ">
            <b>{{key}} </b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;{{val}}
        </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
    <button class="button button-full button-dark" ng-click="showList();">Show Details</button>
</ion-content>
```

Javascript:
I am doing like this which is not working at all as 'present' and 'empty' array are undefined.

```
angular.module('myApp')
.filter('showDataByNotNullFirst', function($filter) {
    return function(array) {
        var present, empty, result;
        //console.log('Key is: ' + key + ' Value is: ' + value);
        $filter('filter')(array, function(key, val) {
            if (val != '-') {
                present[key] = val;
            } else {
                empty[key] = val;
            }
        });
        result = present.concat(empty);
        return result;
    };
});
```

Can any please resolve this or suggest me the solution?

Comment: the [angular documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat#!) is very clear on this matter.  When iterating over object properties, the order of fields is not guaranteed, and sorting **cannot** be applied unless you convert the data to an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would solve this in the controller.

First you would need to convert your object properties to an array.

```
var statusArr = [],
sortedArr = [];


// Loop over every property inside your object
for(var propertyName in appStatusData) {
    var obj = {
        name: propertyName,
        value: m[propertyName]   
    }
    statusArr.push(obj);
}
```

Now lets loop over every item inside your statusArr array.
If the item = '-', *push* it in the new array. If it isn't a '-', *unshift* it in the beginning of the array.

More information about [JavaScript Array methods](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1796-javascript-array-methods-unshift-shift-push-and-pop.htm).

```
angular.forEach(statusArr, function (s) {
    if (s === '-') {
        // add it to the 'right' side of the array
        sortedArr.push(s);
    } else {
        // add it on the 'left' side of the array
        sortedArr.unshift(s);
    }
});
```